# Cairo Linking Causes Memory Leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, cairo

I was messing around with Cairo and quickly realized that even just linking the library (-I/usr/include/cairo) regularly without using it or allocating anything causes memory leaks. **Has anyone had this issue? Is there a piece of cairo-specific code I need to include to avoid leaks when linking?**

Sample Hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling regularly:

gcc -o test test.c -Wall

```
Hello, world!
==19531== 
==19531== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19531==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19531==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==19531== 
==19531== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19531== 
==19531== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19531== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Linking Cairo:

gcc -o test test.c -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo)

```
Hello, world!
==19538== 
==19538== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19538==     in use at exit: 12,384 bytes in 6 blocks
==19538==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 12,384 bytes allocated
==19538== 
==19538== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19538==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19538==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19538==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19538==    still reachable: 12,384 bytes in 6 blocks
==19538==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19538== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==19538== 
==19538== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19538== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Leak-check=full:

```
valgrind ./test --leak-check=full -v --tool=memcheck
==20390== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20390== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20390== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20390== Command: ./test --leak-check=full -v --tool=memcheck
==20390== 
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so:
--20390-- Last block truncated in .debug_info; ignoring
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so:
--20390-- parse_CU_Header: is neither DWARF2 nor DWARF3 nor DWARF4
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.22.so:
--20390-- Last block truncated in .debug_info; ignoring
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.22.so:
--20390-- parse_CU_Header: is neither DWARF2 nor DWARF3 nor DWARF4
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.22.so:
--20390-- Last block truncated in .debug_info; ignoring
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.22.so:
--20390-- parse_CU_Header: is neither DWARF2 nor DWARF3 nor DWARF4
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.22.so:
--20390-- Last block truncated in .debug_info; ignoring
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.22.so:
--20390-- parse_CU_Header: is neither DWARF2 nor DWARF3 nor DWARF4
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.22.so:
--20390-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.22.so:
--20390-- Last block truncated in .debug_info; ignoring
--20390-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--20390-- When reading debug info from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.22.so:
--20390-- parse_CU_Header: is neither DWARF2 nor DWARF3 nor DWARF4
Hello, world!
==20390== 
==20390== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20390==     in use at exit: 12,384 bytes in 6 blocks
==20390==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 12,384 bytes allocated
==20390== 
==20390== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20390==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20390==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20390==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20390==    still reachable: 12,384 bytes in 6 blocks
==20390==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20390== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20390== 
==20390== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20390== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not seeing leaked memory, as such. You're seeing memory that wasn't deallocated via `free()` or the `delete` operator when the application exited, which might or might not be an intentional leak. In my mind, at least, "leaked memory" is memory that **you** could have intentionally deallocated, but didn't.

From the diagnostic output you provided, you can't tell whether the 12,384 bytes were allocated by the `C` runtime or by Cairo. There's also the possibility that the 12K is dynamic linking overhead, which could be the case if Cairo is a `.so` object on your system. In that case, it's runtime overhead that you can't escape.

Basically, without running with `--leak-check=full`, you can't conclusively prove or disprove that the memory is leaked or who leaked it.

And (now) since `valgrind` doesn't provide further insight, and `dmalloc` says that the pointers are foreign, the old school method is: fire up `gdb`, set a breakpoint in `malloc` and look at the backtrace.

Comment: Updated question with full leakcheck and it provides absolutely no insight.

Comment: Well, since it's not __you__ who isn't deallocating and there's not much __you__ can do about other system or library activity, you probably should stop causing yourself anxiety. Unless you can pin down exactly who is allocating 12K and whether anything can be done about it.

Comment: I prefer to stress myself out about it.

Comment: My best educated guess: Cairo is a shared object and the 12K is the cost of attaching the shared object to your process (`ldd` will tell you what shared objects your application uses.) If this turns out to be the case, there's really nothing you can do.

Comment: If you really want to get down and jiggy with `malloc()` and friends, consider using Gray Watson's venerable `dmalloc` library. I'm not sure that `dmalloc` will provide you with additional insight here.

Comment: And ther verdict is! libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fe12060a000)

Comment: So, most likely (I'm guessing), it's dylib overhead. It's the cost of doing business, as it were.

Comment: Dmalloc tells me that "unkown" (probably cairo) callos 6 times at 2064 bytes each and none of them are freed =/

Comment: It could also be the C runtime that's allocating those bytes (although 2064 bytes seems a bit low for `stdio` buffer allocations.)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for stdio to not allocate when it's alone, and allocate when it's linked with cairo.

Comment: `gdb` is now your friend.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Well, sort of. I know you're looking for the answer points, so I'll give it to you strictly because I believe the second paragraph is the main issue. I switched to libpng instead.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with scooter me fecit's answer. Anyway, here is what valgrind tells you if you run it with `--leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes` and also use a debug build of pixman:

```
==3300== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3300==     in use at exit: 12,384 bytes in 6 blocks
==3300==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 12,384 bytes allocated
==3300== 
==3300== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
==3300==    at 0x4C29C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3300==    by 0x575D8AA: _pixman_implementation_create (pixman-implementation.c:38)
==3300==    by 0x575C3EE: _pixman_implementation_create_general (pixman-general.c:250)
==3300==    by 0x575DF45: _pixman_choose_implementation (pixman-implementation.c:388)
==3300==    by 0x57152C8: pixman_constructor (pixman.c:39)
==3300==    by 0x400F2D9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x400F3EA: _dl_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x4000CC9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300== 
==3300== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==3300==    at 0x4C29C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3300==    by 0x575D8AA: _pixman_implementation_create (pixman-implementation.c:38)
==3300==    by 0x575AF3F: _pixman_implementation_create_fast_path (pixman-fast-path.c:3286)
==3300==    by 0x575DF60: _pixman_choose_implementation (pixman-implementation.c:391)
==3300==    by 0x57152C8: pixman_constructor (pixman.c:39)
==3300==    by 0x400F2D9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x400F3EA: _dl_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x4000CC9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300== 
==3300== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==3300==    at 0x4C29C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3300==    by 0x575D8AA: _pixman_implementation_create (pixman-implementation.c:38)
==3300==    by 0x57761DF: _pixman_implementation_create_mmx (pixman-mmx.c:4021)
==3300==    by 0x57433C5: _pixman_x86_get_implementations (pixman-x86.c:234)
==3300==    by 0x575DF6B: _pixman_choose_implementation (pixman-implementation.c:393)
==3300==    by 0x57152C8: pixman_constructor (pixman.c:39)
==3300==    by 0x400F2D9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x400F3EA: _dl_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x4000CC9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300== 
==3300== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==3300==    at 0x4C29C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3300==    by 0x575D8AA: _pixman_implementation_create (pixman-implementation.c:38)
==3300==    by 0x57972BF: _pixman_implementation_create_sse2 (pixman-sse2.c:6487)
==3300==    by 0x57433A5: _pixman_x86_get_implementations (pixman-x86.c:239)
==3300==    by 0x575DF6B: _pixman_choose_implementation (pixman-implementation.c:393)
==3300==    by 0x57152C8: pixman_constructor (pixman.c:39)
==3300==    by 0x400F2D9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x400F3EA: _dl_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x4000CC9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300== 
==3300== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==3300==    at 0x4C29C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3300==    by 0x575D8AA: _pixman_implementation_create (pixman-implementation.c:38)
==3300==    by 0x579795F: _pixman_implementation_create_ssse3 (pixman-ssse3.c:345)
==3300==    by 0x575DF6B: _pixman_choose_implementation (pixman-implementation.c:393)
==3300==    by 0x57152C8: pixman_constructor (pixman.c:39)
==3300==    by 0x400F2D9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x400F3EA: _dl_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x4000CC9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300== 
==3300== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==3300==    at 0x4C29C0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3300==    by 0x575D8AA: _pixman_implementation_create (pixman-implementation.c:38)
==3300==    by 0x57604CF: _pixman_implementation_create_noop (pixman-noop.c:155)
==3300==    by 0x57152C8: pixman_constructor (pixman.c:39)
==3300==    by 0x400F2D9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x400F3EA: _dl_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300==    by 0x4000CC9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.22.so)
==3300== 
==3300== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3300==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3300==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3300==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3300==    still reachable: 12,384 bytes in 6 blocks
==3300==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

What `_pixman_choose_implementation()` does is to look at the CPU's capability and choose the fastest possible code for a various of code. This doesn't count as a real leak, I'd say (plus, this cannot safely be deallocated).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the insight. I prefer my code not having any leaks, regardless of if they're benign or not.

Comment: @user10984587: It'd be nice to live in a perfect world, but, alas, we have to suffer fools gladly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `cairo_debug_reset_static_data()` at the end of the function which calls `cairo_xxx()` to draw text or something. If good, you would only see some reachable loss from `pixman` library, and according to what Uli Schlachter said, it's not a big deal. So things are done.